# why if statement always return false

Tags: java

I want to check it the first input argument is operator "+"

below is the code

```
if (args[0] == "+") {
    System.out.println("good");
} else {
    System.out.println("invalid expression");
}
```

but it always return false. something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

You should compare strings using `str.equals(..)` method and not `==`, which compares object adresses.

```
if (args[0].equals("+")) {
  :
}
```